# how do I maintain divergent code on github

Tags: version-control, github

I have to maintain a base version of code and different "variations" of that code with client specific modifications for different clients sites.

It would be much easier to force all clients on the same variant, or have a super variant that encompasses all clients' needs. However that is not the nature of my world and I can't change it.

Given this environment, what is the best way to use github?

I can create a separate repository for each version. I can create one repository with separate branches. In either case I see how I can use github as a storage medium and version control for each variant, but I don't see how I can use github to help manage the code divergence.

thanks

Comment: 1. Maybe you are confusing GitHub with Git? 2. Git branches seems the best choice to me, but I'm uncertain what would you expect of GitHub to help you *manage* the divergent code.

Comment: thanks for the thought. github is a hosted version of git. so the question is the same for git or github. The problem is keeping track of what files have what changes for different clients. And how to deal with changes within the 'common' section of code. I can't figure out if git can help, and I was hoping that someone with more experience and smarter than I, would have some words of wisdom.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your question I would recommend a single repo, with a master branch. You can use other branches for the "variations".

The tricky part is when a commit is made to master that won't cleanly merge into another branch. You can do a merge commit with `git merge`, but I prefer to do a `git rebase` onto the new `HEAD` of master. This way people using master could easily pull in changes from that branch.

[**Related**](http://github.com/dchelimsky/rspec/wiki/Topic-Branches)