# Using GitHub for an existing website to track my own and vendor code changes

Tags: php, git, version-control, github

I'm going to implement version control for a project via GitHub.  It's a website using mostly PHP and JavaScript.  And we're switching from one script to another.  I'm using cPanel / ftp to access the files.  I would prefer not to mess around with apache config files.

**/home/website/ - home directory**

**/home/website/public_html/** - document root for website.com - has existing php script files which will be overwritten once the beta site is tested to be working properly

**/home/website/public_html/beta.website.com/** - document root for beta.website.com - has existing php script files which have been minimally modified from the original vendor source.  ie header / footer / config files.

**/home/website/public_html/orig.website.com/** - a possible directory where I could update the original vendor files?

**/home/website/public_html/addon-website.com/** - document root for another addon domain - completely separate website has nothing to do with the project

This script is to be used on many different websites.  The difference would be in:

- config files
- template files
- website specific changes

I have the original vendor source files on my local computer but no local web server.  I need help in initial setup.  How should I set things up so I can track all of the following:

- track changes to the original vendor files done via patches and updates
- track changes to 1 or many versions of the original script installed on different websites
- track changes to a beta which has my own modifications to the vendor files
- track website specific changes
- push changes from vendor files to where I do my own modifications
- push changes from my modifications to all different websites / website specific

I had a look at [how do I maintain divergent code on github](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12962439/how-do-i-maintain-divergent-code-on-github) but I need more specific instructions than what is provided there.  Should I even be trying to do this all in one repo with many branches / forks / whatever?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be beneficial to have an integration branch and each party to work on features that are merged there. This is the workflow that I developed with my colleagues and has worked out very well:

http://dymitruk.com/blog/2012/02/05/branch-per-feature/

For an introduction of Git itself, this is a very good resource:

http://git-scm.com/docs

Comment: The discussion there is way beyond my understanding of Git.  I will have to spend some time with manuals and tutorials I think.  The diagram from "A successful Git branching model" was helpful.

Comment: Got a crash course on GitHub.  Am going to be using an implementation very close to what is presented in your post.